# Views Php how to select actual term name not term ID

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

How to select term reference field with variables in views global PHP field?  I need to not Term ID, but actual term name. My views is fields of a content type that contains term reference field. And php field selects term reference fields as term ID. But I need actual term name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a relationship with taxonomy in order for the term name to be available in views as a field, or use [`taxonomy_term_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7).