# How to print taxonomy term name with views PHP?

Tags: 7, views

I have a views that include node title, a text field and a taxonomy term reference field.

I need to print the **taxonomy term name** via Global: PHP field ([Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)) but I couldn't.

**How to print taxonomy term name with Views PHP?**

---

I can print the node title with that code:

**Value Code:**

```
return $row->title;
```

**Output Code:**

```
<?php print $value; ?>
```

or without Value Code:

**Output Code:**

```
<?php print $row->title; ?>
```

And I could print the taxonomy term ID with that code:

**Output Code:**

```
<?php print $data->field_field_my_taxonomy_term[0]['raw']['tid']; ?>
```

But using **name** or **value** instead of **tid** doesn't return anything.

I also tried to print the term name with these ones but unfortunately none of them worked:

```
$data->field_my_taxonomy_term[0]['raw']['value'];
```

(Above code prints nothing.)

```
<?php $data->field_my_taxonomy_term[0]['raw']['taxonomy_term']->name; ?>
```

(Above code prints nothing.)

So, I'm confused now and not know **how to print taxonomy term name with Views PHP?**

Note: I looked at these but still couldn't solve the problem:

1. [Views Php how to select actual term name not term ID](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128047/views-php-how-to-select-actual-term-name-not-term-id)
2. https://www.drupal.org/node/1707002
3. https://www.drupal.org/node/1516348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the term name is in the query for the View, you'll need to load the object to get its properties:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($data->field_field_my_taxonomy_term[0]['raw']['tid']);
$name = $term->name;
```

That will incur a performance cost, so it would be better to add the relationship to the term in the View itself, and add the name as a hidden field. Then you can refer to it without having to load any entities.

Comment: Actually, the term name was in the query for the View but didn't work. 
Now, it's working correctly and I'm very surprised to see the result. Thanks a lot. And a note for the friends in the same situation: my actual field name is field_my_taxonomy_term and in the code above doesn't work without adding the **field_** before field_my_taxonomy_term (so it becomes field_field_my_taxonomy_term). My mistake was that.

Comment: How can I use the code above for multiple terms instead of one? I tried to add a foreach loop but didn't work. If all the nodes have equal numbers of terms it's may be easy but each node can have 0 to 7 terms.

Comment: Yep `foreach` or `for`, either is fine. Can't tell you which/how as I can't see your data, but it should be straightforward in theory

Comment: For **multiple terms** you can use that code: `foreach($data->field_field_my_taxonomy as $mydata) {
$term = taxonomy_term_load($mydata['raw']['tid']);
...`
}

Answer (score 2):

Storing PHP code directly on database is not a correct method, it causes many issues. Better you can add the relations on your views - "Content: Taxonomy terms on node". and then add the taxonomy term name field as a "hidden field"

Print the value via "Global: Custom text" field if required any custom wrapper around of it.

Comment: Yes, I know "storing PHP code directly on database" is not a good way but I'm using this View just for a while (to export data). And because I'm manipulating the term name, using "Global: Custom text" doesn't work for this case. Thanks.